# How to avoid changed score after overwriting a document in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, scoring

After overwriting a document with an updated version the score for it changes, even if the query doesn't target any of the changed fields.

I've found out, that overwriting a document causes the old one to be flagged as deleted and a new one is created (*[Elasticsearch Reference [1.7] » Document APIs » Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/update-doc.html)*). as a consequence, the number of maxDocs increases by one and both documents are used for idf (*[inversed document frequency](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#idf)*). Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: You might find this question useful, might even be a dup of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851093/why-lucene-uses-maxdoc-instead-of-numdocs-to-compute-term-idf

Comment: One solution, if you truly need scoring stability, is to create a custom similarity and add some debouncing to the document frequency changes, perhaps ensuring they change only once per second or so?